# How to override links in each Views feeds?

Tags: 6, views

I would like to override all links in all views feeds through a hook (potentially) - for example adding an extra query param to each item links. 
I need a general function. When defining a new feed, the field name is unknown, so I can't rely on the exact name -> cannot use a specific preprocess hook.
I checked all Views hooks here: http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views%21docs%21docs.php/6 but couldn't find a right one. I was playing a lot with different preprocess functions, no luck.
One idea is to override a field handler, but I'm not sure how to execute that.

What would you suggest?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the url_alter module: http://drupal.org/project/url_alter,

Some details from the module's project page:

> URL alter is a utility module that adds two new hooks for other modules to implement: hook_url_inbound_alter() and hook_url_outbound_alter(). These hooks also replace the need for the special, silly custom_url_rewrite_inbound() and custom_url_rewrite_outbound() functions commonly found in settings.php.
>
> It also provides an interface for administrators to enter in their own hook_url_alter code without needing to create a custom module.

It has some usable hooks:

```
hook_url_inbound_alter() and hook_url_outbound_alter()
```